# Getting a "NoSuchElementException" when I tried to include HTML details of a login button when building a bot

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, bots

I have been trying to implement a simple bot in python which increases Instagram followers. This is what I was trying-> https://towardsdatascience.com/increase-your-instagram-followers-with-a-simple-python-bot-fde048dce20d During the process, I installed chromedriver as specified in the above-mentioned post and included the path of it in the webdriver.chrome. I gathered the HTML element (the copy selector) of the login button present in Instagram and pasted it in the find_element_by_name method but I am getting an error stating "NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > button "}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)"

Kindly find my code below and help me sort this error. Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
```

`webdriver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Vishal\\chromedriver.exe")`

```
sleep(2)
```

`webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')`

```
sleep(3)
```

`username = webdriver.find_element_by_name('#react-root > section > main > div > article > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > button ')`

Comment: @QHarr yes thank you. got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a couple of waits to ensure visibility and that login can be clicked. Use a shorter selector to target button. Note you need to add values to first two login fields for button to be clickable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name=username]"))).send_keys('bob')
d.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=password]').send_keys('builder')
WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form div:nth-of-type(3)"))).click()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am new to working on selenium. I am just following the instructions provided on a website. What do you mean by "Use a short selector to target button"? By waits, it means, the automated program will take time to load hence we are applying the wait condition? And what are the "First 2 login fields"?

Comment: As in I have used a shorter CSS selector to target the button as shown above. I just find it more readable and it is likely faster. Yes you need a wait before you can find the input boxes after selenium starts. First two login fields: I mean username and password. You can see the name attributes referred to in the above code where I use CSS attribute selectors, indicated by []

Comment: Try it and see how it goes. Any further questions let me know.

Comment: This should nail the OP